# Checking if input is empty on form validation, why is it always false?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to run a function on a Todo list that when a todo is added. A function will check the input box to check if its empty and if its empty, not do anything.

However, after using the function to check if the input is empty, it always returns False even when its empty. Where is the bug here?

The function name in question is "checkInput()" and it runs from the main submit button on the page

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { isTemplateElement } from "@babel/types";

class TodoListt extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      userInput: "",
      list: [],
    };
  }

  changeUserInput(input) {
    this.setState({
      userInput: input
    })
  }


  addToList() {
    const { list, userInput } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      list: [...list, {
        text: userInput, key: Date.now(), done: false
      }],
      userInput: ''
    })
  }

  handleChecked(e, index) {
    console.log(e.target.checked);
    const list = [...this.state.list];
    list[index] = { ...list[index] };
    list[index].done = e.target.checked;
    this.setState({
      list
    })
  }

  checkInput() {
    console.log(this.state.userInput);
    userInput: '' ? console.log("True") : console.log("False")
  }


  render() {


    return (
      <div className="to-do-list-main">
        <input
          onChange={(e) => this.changeUserInput(e.target.value)}
          value={this.state.userInput}
          type="text"
        />
        <button onClick={() => { this.checkInput(); { this.addToList(this.state.userInput) } }}>Add todo</button>

        {this.state.list.map((list, index) => (
          <div className="form">
            <ul>

              <li><input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => this.handleChecked(e, index)} />
                <span style={{ textDecoration: list.done ? 'line-through' : 'inherit' }}>
                  {list.text}
                </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        ))}


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoListt;
```

Comment: It should be: `this.state.userInput === '' ? console.log("True") : console.log("False")`. You are checking `userInput:`.

Comment: I knew it was a silly mistake, thanks!